# Evolution - exchange-connector, Rackspace global catalog server

Tags: evolution, ms-exchange

I'm (trying to) switch to Ubuntu from Windows XP on my work laptop. Unfortunately, one of the dealbreakers is that I need full Exchange contact/calendar syncing.

Our email is hosted by Rackspace (owa.mailseat.com). We login using the usernames of the format first.lastname@ourcompany.com.

I'm trying to set up Evolution to use this account, using exchange-connector-setup-2.32. The first step, entering the OWA URL, usename and password works, and progresses to step 2, where I need to enter a Global Catalog server. I have no idea what to enter here. Everything fails.

My questions are
- What is the "Global Catalog server" - can I enter/run some dummy server here?
- If its necessary, where can I get the information from this? I have a Windows XP machine synced up using Outlook 2007, so if I need to gather any information from that setup I can.

Comment: What version of Exchange is running on the server?

Answer (score 1):

The Global Catalog Server name can be found in your outlook Names

Steps below

- Open a new email message in Outlook.

then

- Click on the "To:" button to get the
  "Select Names" dialog

then

- Put "Show Names from the" to "Global
  Address List".

finally

- Right-click on the "Global Address
  List" to get "Properties"

This opens a dialog with the name of the Global Address List server and the path. You just need the server name and plug this into Evolution.

You can always change your email application to Thunderbird instead if it is more compatible with an Exchange server setup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've put that in (its of the form 12345-various letters.exchange.rackspace.com), but that doesn't work - It tells me "LDAP authentication failed (oxfffffff Can't contact LDAP server). I couldn't find any options to allow Thunderbird to sync with Exchange, it only seemed to offer IMAP options.